# How does $mdDialog work with promise and $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm new to angular, trying to use angular material to create a popup dialog. I'm confused with the promise and $scope here. If I click the dialog button, console will show 'created' and then no window will popup.
But if I change it to `.then(createFolder, ..)`, `function createFolder(){...}`, everything is ok.

```
$scope.createFolder = function(ev) {
  $mdDialog.show({
    controller: dialogController,
    templateUrl: 'dialog_new_folder.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose:true,
  })
  .then($scope.createFolder, $scope.cancelDialog);
};

$scope.createFolder = function() {
  console.log('created')
}
$scope.cancelDialog = function() {
  console.log('cancelled')
}


function dialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
          $scope.folderName = '';
          $scope.hide = function() {
            $mdDialog.hide();
          }
          $scope.cancel = function() {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `$scope.createFolder` for both the function to call when the dialog is closed successfully, and for the function to show the dialog.  Your second declaration is overwriting your first.  Rename one of them.